# Take a Screenshot Android java in API 29

Tags: java, android, screenshot

I want to take a screenshot in my android application and I'm required to use api 29 for my app so can't use any solutions with functions like `View.setDrawingCacheEnabled` or `View.getDrawingCache()` that were
deprecated in api 28.
couldn't find any solution without these functions

Comment: Use the media projection APIs on Android 5.0+.